# SharePoint 2013 Search: JavaScript object model get alternate access mapping

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, alternate-access-mapping, display-template

I am using a custom item template for search results. In that I ma getting the links as the original ones and not the Alternate Access Mapping.

Is there a way to transform the original URL's to the AAM ones in my item template.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the AAM? If so you should do a full crawl.

If you just want to transform them, AFAIK there is no builtin function for that, other than string.replace.